# Batch progress counter

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm working on a progress counter, but what is wrong in code? This always shows 0% and closes the app.

```
@echo off
set /a i=0
set /a limit=100
set /a percent=0
echo %percent% percent
:execute
set /a i+=1
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 > nul
set /a percent = %i%/%limit%
cls
echo %percent% percent
if %i% LSS %limit% (goto execute) else exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**warning**: A usual problem with variable definition is the inclusion of spaces in the variable name:

```
set /a percent = %i%/%limit%
              ^
              This space "can" be included in the name of the variable
```

While `set /a` uses its own parser and will discard the indicated space, the rest of the `set` command alternatives will create variables with a space in their names. It is *"better/safer/recommended"* to remove the space.

**problem**: How batch arithmetic works. All the arithmetic operators return only integer values.

```
set /a percent= %i% / %limit%
                    ^
                    Batch arithmetic handle only integers
                    i/limit will be always 0 for any i < limit
```

Change to

```
set /a percent= i * 100 / limit
```

In this case there is *no need to use* (but can be used, of course) `%i%` to get the variable value. As said, `set /a` uses its own parser and it will resolve the variable reference retrieving the adecuated value.

Comment: Actually using `SET /A` is the only time you can have a space between the variable name and the assignment operator without it affecting the actual variable name.

Comment: @Squashman, my fault. Answer updated to expose the indicated behaviour. Anyway I think it is better to keep the space removal recomendation.